# There's some sort of error within this code which I am unable to identify

Tags: align, fractions, gather

```
\begin{gather}    
\begin{align}    
F&=mg    
\[F&=\frac{-GMm}{r^2}\]\\    
mg&= \[\frac{-GMm}{r^2}\]\\    
g&=\[\frac{-GM}{r^2}\]\\    
\end{align}    
\end{gather}
```

Comment: The `-` is wrong actually unless specified in a formula using vectors

Answer (score 1):

Equation environments for display cannot be nested. Environment `aligned` can be used instead of `align` inside `gather`. And `\[`...`\]` should not be used at all inside other math environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{gather}
    \begin{aligned}
      F &= mg \\
      F &= \frac{-GMm}{r^2} \\
      mg &= \frac{-GMm}{r^2} \\
      g &= \frac{-GM}{r^2}
   \end{aligned}
  \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with gather and aligned]

Or, if each equation should be numbered:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    F &= mg \\
    F &= \frac{-GMm}{r^2}  \\
    mg &= \frac{-GMm}{r^2}  \\
    g &= \frac{-GM}{r^2}
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with align]

Documentation for the equation environments of `amsmath`, see ["Users' Guide for the `amsmath` Package" (amsldoc)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf).